# How to resolve 'error calling partial: partial "gallerydeluxe/head.html" not found '

Tags: hugo, hugo-theme

I am [using a theme](https://github.com/bep/galleriesdeluxe/blob/main/layouts/_default/single.html) and when I created my first content 'index.md' I am getting this error:

```
    render: failed to render pages: render of "page" failed: 
[1;36m"/Users/laptop/Documents/coding/quickstart/themes/gallerydeluxe/layouts/_default/single.html:6:5"[0m: 
execute of template failed at <partial "gallerydeluxe/head.html" .>: 
error calling partial: partial "gallerydeluxe/head.html" not found
```

but the files are there under themes/gallerydeluxe/layouts

```
        ├── layouts
        │   ├── _default
        │   │   ├── about.html
        │   │   ├── baseof.html
        │   │   ├── head.html
        │   │   ├── list.html
        │   │   ├── single.html
        │   │   └── term.html
        │   └── partials
        │       └── galleriesdeluxe
        │           ├── footer.html
        │           ├── get-gallery.html
        │           ├── head.html
        │           ├── header.html
        │           └── list-gallery.html
```

[The theme](https://github.com/bep/galleriesdeluxe/blob/main/layouts/_default/single.html) doesn't have a file named head, so I renamed the file named 'header' to 'head.html'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder is named galleriesdeluxe, but it is searching in gallerydeluxe. You can create the file `gallerydeluxe/head.html`.